# counting records in an access table that occur between 2 dates

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

first the problem 
i have a table with 2 dates I'm trying to create a function i can pass the 2 dates to work out the number of working days between these dates

i have another table that contains a list of days which are non-working (such as local holidays etc) this table is called [CNNWDATE].
it is structured as below.

NWDATE      NWDAY   DNDAY

29/03/2002   T       F

01/04/2002   T       F

02/04/2002   T       F

06/05/2002   T       F

the structure of these tables is created by another piece of software.  their structure cannot be changed and i have no control over them.  they are linked tables from an oracle database

i found this link which was a good start to what i was after http://www.databasedev.co.uk/calculate_work_days.html
and created the following function

```
Public Function Work_Days(BegDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
'calculate number of working days between to dates
'note this relys on CNNWDATE having been completed with non working days marked

Dim intNMB_NonW_Days As Integer
Dim WholeWeeks As Variant
Dim DateCnt As Variant
Dim EndDays As Integer

  On Error GoTo Err_Work_Days
  BegDate = DateValue(BegDate)
  EndDate = DateValue(EndDate)
  WholeWeeks = DateDiff("w", BegDate, EndDate)
  DateCnt = DateAdd("ww", WholeWeeks, BegDate)
  EndDays = 0


   intNMB_NonW_Days = 0

'count cnnwdate btween dates
    intNMB_NonW_Days = DCount("*", "[CNNWDATE]", "[CNNWDATE.NWDATE] >= _ 
      BegDate and [CNNWDATE.NWDATE] <= Enddate")

    Do While DateCnt <= EndDate
     If Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sun" And _
       Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sat" Then
        EndDays = EndDays + 1
     End If
           DateCnt = DateAdd("d", 1, DateCnt)
  Loop

  Work_Days = WholeWeeks * 5 + EndDays - intNMB_NonW_Days

Exit Function

Err_Work_Days:

  If Err.Number = 94 Then
     Work_Days = 0
        Exit Function
  Else
     MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
  End If

End Function
```

if i comment out the DCOUNT i get the number of week days but i cannot get DCOUNT to actually return a number of non-working days in CNNWDATE

the error i get is

Error 2766: the object doesn't contain the Automation object 'BegDate'

Any help on where I'm going wrong appreciated

Comment: *i have a table with 2 dates I'm trying to create a function i can pass the 2 dates to work out the number of working days between these dates* Why function? it can be calculated using expression in SQL...

Comment: primarily because i need to do this for many different reports (there are over 100 tables on the oracle database with 10's of thousands of records) and there is a potential for some very large datasets 

so being able to call a function in the future is much easier than redoing the sql every time

Comment: *there are over 100 tables on the oracle* Then I do not understand why do something in the Access, when all the same, but much more effectively, can be performed directly in the Oracle.

Comment: because the oracle database is locked down by the vendor of the other application.  the only access to the data i have is via ODBC links to the oracle database

Comment: ODBC can send (transfer from your application) the query text to Oracle and receive its execution result. Quering the whole table content is not the only way to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really daft posting this now as i stumbled on this post about DCOUNT https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/963055-object-doesnt-contain-automation-object

and creating the string to pass to DCOUNT first then passing it has solved the problem so my code now reads

```
   Public Function Work_Days(BegDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
'calculate number of working days between to dates
'note this relys on CNNWDATE haveing been completed with non working days marked


Dim intNMB_NonW_Days As Integer
Dim WholeWeeks As Variant
Dim DateCnt As Variant
Dim EndDays As Integer
Dim sSQL As String


  On Error GoTo Err_Work_Days
  BegDate = DateValue(BegDate)
  EndDate = DateValue(EndDate)


  WholeWeeks = DateDiff("w", BegDate, EndDate)
  DateCnt = DateAdd("ww", WholeWeeks, BegDate)
  EndDays = 0
  intNMB_NonW_Days = 0

'count cnnwdate between dates

sSQL = "[NWDATE] >=#" & CDate(BegDate) & "# and [NWDATE] <=#" & CDate(EndDate) & "#"
intNMB_NonW_Days = DCount("*", "[CNNWDATE]", sSQL)

  Do While DateCnt <= EndDate
     If Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sun" And _
       Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sat" Then
        EndDays = EndDays + 1
     End If
           DateCnt = DateAdd("d", 1, DateCnt)
  Loop

  Work_Days = WholeWeeks * 5 + EndDays - intNMB_NonW_Days

Exit Function

Err_Work_Days:

  If Err.Number = 94 Then
     Work_Days = 0
        Exit Function
  Else
     MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
  End If

End Function
```